# Split string by line who start with specific value

Tags: c#, string, list, split

I'm trying to split a huge string into different "sections". These section are delimited by this line `#=========================================================`. The problem is each string have a different delimiter (not the same amount of ====)

```cs
List<Section> sections = file.GetSections("#=========================================================");
```

```cs
List<Section> sections = file.GetSections("#=========================================");
```

```cs
public List<Section> GetSections(string separator)
{
    List<Section> sections = new List<Section>();
    string[] values = _fileContent.Split(separator);

    foreach (string value in values)
    {
        sections.Add(new Section(value));
    }

    return sections;
}
```

As you can see, I need to change the delimiter according to the file I'm using, since all delimiter start with `#====`. I would like to know if it's possible to split by "line who start with `#====`"

Comment: I am pretty sure Regex can do this. But I can not really provide you code, as regex is not something I fully understood yet myself. But it does sound like what it was meant to do.

Comment: Regex is probably the easiest. However a good old fashioned for loop and a state machine would be super easier and super fast as well. State one, You are in are in text, state two you have found a hash, state three you have in a bunch of equals

Comment: Does the first section start with the delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a good tool to use here. For example:

```
return Regex.Split(input, @"^#====[=]*\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .Select(s => new Section(s));
```

In this example, the regex pattern (`^#====[=]*\s*$`) matches portions of the input string which:

1. Start with a newline (`^`)
2. Have `#====` immediately following that newline.
3. May have some number of `=` signs following that.
4. May have some whitespace following that (important because there will often be an invisible `\r` character there).
5. Ends with a newline (`$`).

You'll likely need to tweak this based on some of your specific requirements. For example, `@"^#====[=]*\s*(\r\n|\r|\n)?` can be used to include the newline (`\n`) itself in the pattern, ensuring that this extra character isn't included at the start of each Section. Or you might want to add a `.Select(s => s.Trim())` to get rid of all extra whitespace between sections.

Answer (score 0):

A problem like this can very easily be solve by a good old fashioned for loop and a statemachine. Though for ease of use I chucked it in Iterator method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetStrings(string input)
{
   var state = 0;
   var sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach (var c in input)
   {
      if (state == 0 && c != '#')
         sb.Append(c);
      if (state == 0)
      {
         yield return sb.ToString();
         sb.Clear();
         state = 1;
      }
      if (state == 1) 
          state = 2;
      else if (c != '=') 
          state = 0;
   }

   yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "asdasda#===fgsdfsdfdg#====";

foreach (var str in GetStrings(input))
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

I do think regex is more succinct; however, this is school yard stuff and extremely fast.

In short though, I'd use regex, less code easier to understand and maintain.

Note this will fail on '#' as text in a string by itself. You could check in state '1'.